# Get Values from XML File in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a file currently written like so:

```
<values>
  <Item ID="1" Type="Command" Value="330MV,60HZ"/>
  <Item ID="2" Type="Command" Value="600MV,13KHZ"/>
  <Item ID="3" Type="Command" Value="3.3V,60HZ"/>
  <Item ID="4" Type="Notification" Value="Look At This!!!" />
</values>
```

The file itself will be dynamic as lots of variables need to be added. My current goal is to load the entire file, increment through each item by the `ID`, check the `Type`, and, depending on what `Type` is set as, do something with `Value`

How would I do this?

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: you could use the xmlreader http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Not much. Just `XDocument myxml = XDocument.Load(@"config.xml");
            var query = myxml.DescendantNodes();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using `System.XML.Linq;`

```
var xmlDoc = xDocument.Load("text.xml");
var items = xmlDoc.Element("values").Elements("Item").Select(i => new { 
ID = i.Attribute("ID").Value,
Type = i.Attribute("Type").Value,
Value = i.Attribute("Value").Value
});

foreach(var _item in items)
{
  //write your logic

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var doc = XDocument.Parse("<xml . ../>");

    foreach (var item in doc.Element("Values").Elements("Item").OrderBy(x=>x.Attribute("ID").Value))
    {

        var type = item.Attribute("Type").Value;

        if (type=="Notification")
        {
           // processing code here
        }
    }
```